# How can a glute be developed to twerk?

Tags: bodybuilding, strength-training, hypertrophy, glutes, weighttraining

It seems that most people who are able to twerk have big glutes, not necessarily muscular but a big fatty.

Is it necessary to have a fat deposits on glute muscles to be able to get the control?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because while the title asks about developing glutes, the question asks about apparent fat amounts on twerking people. There is nothing fitness related.

Comment: I respect your opinion,but ability of twerk seem to be directly related to the size and control of the glutes.While muscle-fat ratio of the region seems to be mostly dependent on genetics but can be slightly altered through glutes focus exercise and glute specific workouts help in the activation of the muscles mind connection of the said muscles.

Answer (score 2):

You need to be genetically predisposed towards storing fat on your buttocks, and then you need to have a sufficiently high body fat percentage to have a fat butt.

It's not something that can be trained in the gym, as muscle doesn't jiggle.